# Modify Ids on delete Oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

```
ID VALUE
0   2
1   3
2   0
```

When the first record with id 0 is deleted the second one should become 0 and the third one should be 1 .

Resulting in:

```
ID VALUE
0   3
1   0
```

When the record with id 1 is deleted the third one should become 1 .

```
ID VALUE
0   2
1   0
```

Which ever one is deleted the consecutive order should be maintained starting from 0.

This id is not the primary key. Should be done on delete in the trigger.

Comment: You cannot have a trigger modifying other records in the same table that the trigger is executing on (mutating trigger) without some kludgey workarounds.  Better to write a stored procedure to encapsulate the logic.

Comment: _"Should be done on delete in the trigger"_ Is that an absurd requirement imposed to you by, say, ... a teacher ? Please note that homework is expressively *allowed* in SO. There is nothing wrong with that. But knowing it might help us to point you in the right direction without waisting anyone's time.

Comment: Are you just trying to make then contiguous for display purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't modify the same table in the trigger, you will run into mutating table issues.

An alternative is to use a stored procedure and call it after you delete the record. Just select all IDs greater than your deleted ID, and subtract 1 from them.

```
PROCEDURE UPDATE_IDS(deletedID in Number) IS
  BEGIN
    UPDATE table t
    SET ID = ID - 1
    WHERE ID > deletedID;
END UPDATE_IDS;
```

Comment: This works. and Thank you. But can you tell me what has to be done when multiple ids are deleted at a time. the ids can be random. like 0 and 16 or 23 and 27 and 29.

Comment: just iterate through your array of deleted ids can call the proc once for each number

Comment: But the Ids will be modified from the first  iteration in the for loop. In the second iteration it will delete the wrong id.

Comment: yeah, so do it in reverse order from largest id to smallest